# use of regular expression in Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

Tags: regex, asp-classic

The URL is for example: `http://www.somedomain.com/24-sale.htm`

this work fine:

```
Response.Redirect _
    Replace(
        Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"), _
        "24" & "-sale.htm", _
        "contact_confirm.htm" _
    )
'if there the message is sent return 1 to flash
```

But... on the place of the number 24 there can be any number from 1 to 999
Did try to place a regular expression on the place of "24" as follow:

```
Response.Redirect _
    Replace( _
        Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"),
        "^([0-9]{1,3})$" & "-sale.htm",
        "contact_confirm.htm"
     )
'if there the message is sent return 1 to flash
```

This will not work at al... ;-(

anyone know the correct syntax for that ?
spend allready hundreds of hours to figure it out....

After a lot of trial and errors I ended up with this:

Dim refererStr : refererStr = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

Dim regex : Set regex = New RegExp

RegEx.Pattern = RegEx.replace("^([1-9]{1,3})$","")

Dim redirectTo : redirectTo = Replace("refererStr"),"-sale.htm","contact_confirm.htm")

Response.Redirect redirectTo ) 'if there the message is sent return 1 to flash

but not working :-(

someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript's `Replace` function does not accept Regular expressions as arguments, you must use the `RegExp` object to perform regex operations.

`RegExp` is documented here ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx ) and here ( http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html )

You want something like this:

```
Dim refererStr : refererStr = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

Dim regex : Set regex = New RegExp
regex.Pattern = "^([1-9]{1,3})$"

Dim redirectTo : redirectTo = regex.Replace( refererStr, "-sale.html" )

Response.Redirect redirectTo
```

Comment: Dai, First thank you for pointing me in the right direction !